# Git pull in Intellij causes Xcode errors

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am so confused as to how this is happening. I am using Intellij Ultimate on my Mac book Pro and did not change any settings. Everything was working fine on Friday. Now when I try to pull latest changes for my master or switch to another branch from remote, I get following errors. Does anyone knows how to resolve this? Thanks.

Error:

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run 'sudo xcodebuild --
license' and then retry this command.

The suggested comment is a sudo command which I do not have access to. My development is in Java thus there is no relevance for Xcode and iOS stuff anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your git binary is provided by XCode (which is an easy way to get many command-line tools). If you don't like this, you can install it manually. So actually it's git throwing an error, not IntelliJ. If you try to perform pull via terminal you may see the same behavior. 
You can open an Xcode and **accept user agreement** or **request sudo credentials**.